# Which spring version is right when work with Hessian(3.1.3)?

Tags: java, spring, hessian

Now i start a hession server with spring（3.2.3.RELAESE)+Hession(3.1.3), then i run a client to call the server, it always print errors as follows:

```
[12:54:20.876] org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Hessian skeleton invocation failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.caucho.hessian.io.AbstractHessianInput.close()V
[12:54:20.876]  at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianServiceExporter.handleRequest(HessianServiceExporter.java:69)
[12:54:20.876]  at org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet.service(HttpRequestHandlerServlet.java:68)
[12:54:20.876]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:92)
[12:54:20.876]  at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletFilterChain.doFilter(ServletFilterChain.java:106)
[12:54:20.876]  at com.sogou.adcore.filter.SecureFilter.doFilter(SecureFilter.java:87)
[12:54:20.876]  at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:70)
[12:54:20.876]  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
[12:54:20.876]  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
[12:54:20.876]  at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:70)
[12:54:20.876]  at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:173)
[12:54:20.876]  at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletInvocation.service(ServletInvocation.java:229)
[12:54:20.876]  at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.handleRequest(HttpRequest.java:274)
[12:54:20.876]  at com.caucho.server.port.TcpConnection.run(TcpConnection.java:511)
[12:54:20.876]  at com.caucho.util.ThreadPool.runTasks(ThreadPool.java:520)
[12:54:20.876]  at com.caucho.util.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:442)
[12:54:20.876]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[12:54:20.876] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.caucho.hessian.io.AbstractHessianInput.close()V
[12:54:20.876]  at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianExporter.doInvoke(HessianExporter.java:202)
[12:54:20.876]  at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianExporter.invoke(HessianExporter.java:118)
[12:54:20.876]  at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianServiceExporter.handleRequest(HessianServiceExporter.java:66)
[12:54:20.876]  ... 15 more
```

i know it's not work well as (spring+hession)'s compatible..

Which spring version should i choose??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a client working with Spring 3.2.8 and Hessian 3.2.

Hope this helps.